# ASP.net VB String builder double double quotes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stringbuilder

I've been going around in circles on this.  Every time I try to build this string with a single double-quote character, it looks like it adds two of the double-quote characters in a row, so I end up with double double quotes. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
sb.Append("[")
For i As Integer = 0 To datMemberlist.Rows.Count - 1
    sb.Append("""")
    sb.Append(datMemberlist.Rows(i).Item("Name"))
    sb.Append("""" & ", ")
Next
strUsers = sb.ToString.Remove(sb.ToString.Length - 2, 2)
strUsers = strUsers & "]"
```

I am expecting `"["FirstName LastName", "FirstName LastName"]"`, but I am getting `"[""FirstName LastName"", ""FirstName LastName""]"`.

Comment: Have you checked that the data in `datMemberlist.Rows(i).Item("Name")` does not already have double-quotes around it?

Comment: And you could replace the code with `Dim strUsers = "[" & String.Join(", ", datMemberlist.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) r.Item("Name"))) & "]"` if the data does already have double-quotes.

Comment: How are you inspecting the result?  If you're looking in the debugger, then the debugger will show the the double characters.  Have you tried printing to the console or writing to a file and inspecting it there?

Comment: I hadn't realised that visual studio shows "" in immediate window, once i printed it out to the console it came through correct (as per the advice in the duplicate post mentioned above).